# Style to make axis tick label opaque

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I would like to make a specific tick label have a white opaque fill around it, so that the a line does not cross over it.  Ideally I would like to be able to specify exactly which tick, but do not have an elegant method to do that, so below I attempted to use:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Y Tick Label/.append style={
    yticklabel style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, fill=white, text opacity=1}
    }
}
```

to apply to *all* the `yticklabel`s.  This achieves the effect I want (note the `y=-2` label):

[image]

But it also has the unwanted side effect of shifting the `yticklabel` to the right.
Well that to me seemed like I just need to use `.append style` instead of `.style` so that the prior settings don't get thrown away:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Y Tick Label Append/.append style={
    yticklabel/.append style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, fill=white, text opacity=1}
    }
}
```

but using this seems to have absolutely no effect.

### Note:

- All the tick labels are manually specified, and I know exactly which particular tick labels to apply it on -- in case that simplifies the solution to Question 2 below.
- Follow up question posted at [Style to make axis tick label opaque using "extra y tick" feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51862/style-to-make-axis-tick-label-opaque-using-extra-y-tick-feature)

### Questions:

1. How do I get an opaque tick label without adjusting its location?
2. Is there a way where I can apply this only on a specific tick label?
3. Is there perhaps a better way of doing this? I thought about changing the drawing of the asymptote but that is a bit more complicated.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\XMin}{-2}%
\newcommand{\XMax}{2}%

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Axis Style/.append style={
    width=6cm, height=8cm,
    xmin=\XMin, xmax=\XMax, ymin=-3.2, ymax=5,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis on top=true,
    ytick={       -4,  -3,   -2, -1,  1,  2,   3,  4},
    yticklabels={$-4$, $$, $-2$, $$, $$, $2$, $$, $4$},
    }
}

\newcommand*{\AddPlotFunction}{\addplot[smooth, ultra thick, domain=\XMin:\XMax, red]  {exp(x)-2} node [left] {$y=e^x-2$}}%
\newcommand*{\AddPlotAsymptote}{\addplot[smooth, thin,        domain=\XMin:\XMax, blue] {-2} node [below left] {$y=-2$}}%

%---------- Above is to improve readability of MWE

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Y Tick Label/.append style={
    yticklabel style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, fill=white, text opacity=1}
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Y Tick Label Append/.append style={
    yticklabel/.append style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, fill=white, text opacity=1}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[My Axis Style,
    %My Y Tick Label,%        This shifts the labels to right
    %My Y Tick Label Append,% This has no effect
    ]

    \AddPlotFunction;
    \AddPlotAsymptote;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[My Axis Style,
    My Y Tick Label,%        This shifts the labels to right
    %My Y Tick Label Append,% This has no effect
    ]

    \AddPlotFunction;
    \AddPlotAsymptote;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can win back the shift effect by also adding an `outer xsep=3pt`.

Comment: Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you could use     `yticklabels={$-4$, $$, \colorbox{white}{$-2$}, $$, $$, $2$, $$, $4$}` when defining the labels.

Comment: @percusse: Well that gets it very close, but there is still some shift. Would be better to append the style in case there are other adjustments necessary as well.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yep that works. I also added `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` so as to minimize the effect on any possible drawings nearby. You should make that an answer as that is perfectly useable for the case where one wants to apply that to a particular tick label.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Seems as if I want to use a different value of `\fboxsep` then the label shifts.

Comment: @PeterGrill: yes, that's true and I've just noticed it. I had turned my comment into an answer, but in view of this new undesired fact, I will delete it in wait of a robust, more general solution.

Comment: Perhaps the `extra y tick` feature helps here? It allows to provide one or more custom ticks - with its own set of styles...?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Yep that would certainly help, but still need to know how to set the style so that it appends to the existing style for the tick label as opposed to overwriting it (which is as far as I got to it working).

Comment: Are you sure that your are effectively *overwriting* the old style? It seems to me that you are appending. And it seems as if the location remains the same (you can verify that by setting `anchor=center`). I believe you experience a shift due to the `inner sep=0` key. Perhaps you can compensate for that shift using `yticklabel shift`..?

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Style to make axis tick label opaque using “extra y tick” feature](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51862/style-to-make-axis-tick-label-opaque-using-extra-y-tick-feature).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using an explicit `yticklabels` list, I would use `ytick={-4,-2,...,4}, minor y tick num=1, minor tick length=0.15cm` (`0.15cm` is the standard length of the major ticks, so this way the minor and major tick marks would look identical). You can then set the background for all labels to white, without the unwanted side effect of empty labels showing up as white squares.

To avoid the shift introduced by setting `inner sep=0pt` (which is  necessary because otherwise the white background would be too large), you have to set `outer sep=0.3333em` (which is the value the inner sep had before).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\XMin}{-2}%
\newcommand{\XMax}{2}%

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Axis Style/.append style={
    width=6cm, height=8cm,
    xmin=\XMin, xmax=\XMax, ymin=-3.2, ymax=5,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis on top=true,
    ytick={-4,-2,...,4},
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor tick length=0.15cm
    }
}

\newcommand*{\AddPlotFunction}{\addplot[smooth, ultra thick, domain=\XMin:\XMax, red]  {exp(x)-2} node [left] {$y=e^x-2$}}%
\newcommand*{\AddPlotAsymptote}{\addplot[smooth, thin,        domain=\XMin:\XMax, blue] {-2} node [below left] {$y=-2$}}%


\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Y Tick Label/.append style={
    yticklabel style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.3333em, fill=white, text opacity=1}
    }
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[My Axis Style,
    My Y Tick Label,
    ]

    \AddPlotFunction;
    \AddPlotAsymptote;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the setting of `inner sep` reset the value of `outer sep`? Just wondering if the style is really being appended?  Also, how could I apply this to only certain tick labels, and not _all_ tick labels?

Comment: It doesn't reset the value of `outer sep`, but by default `outer sep` is 0 (well, it's `0.5\pgflinewidth`, but almost). But by setting the inner sep to `0pt`, the nodes become smaller (the inner sep added empty space around the node content) and thus move to the right, because they're snugly aligned with the axis. So to compensate, you need to add the space that you removed with `inner sep=0pt` back in by setting `outer sep=<the value that inner sep used to be>`.

Comment: I think the best way to apply a style to only certain tick labels is to use the `extra y ticks`, as suggested by Christian, but that would mean that you have to go back to supplying explicit tick label lists. I think giving all labels a white background is the better solution in this case, it's much more straightforward and it shouldn't do any harm.