# Style to make axis tick label opaque using "extra y tick" feature

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

This is a follow up to [Style to make axis tick label opaque](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/style-to-make-axis-tick-label-opaque), where a suggestion was made to use the `extra y ticks` to specify special tick marks and use `extra y tick style` to apply a style to only those tick labels.

I attempted to adapt Jake's answer to the above referenced question and apply that by making `-2` not a normal tick, but an `extra y tick`:

```
ytick={-1,1,2,3,4},%    Note: -2 not listed here
extra y ticks={-2},% 
extra y tick style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.3333em, fill=white, text opacity=1},
```

but this does not seem to have **any** effect on the `y tick label` at `-2`:

[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\XMin}{-2.2}%
\newcommand{\XMax}{1.5}%

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/My Axis Style/.append style={
    width=7cm, height=8cm,
    xmin=\XMin, xmax=\XMax, ymin=-3.2, ymax=2.5,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis on top=true,
    ytick={-1,1,2},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick style={draw=none, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0.3333em, fill=white, text opacity=1},
    }
}

\newcommand*{\AddPlotFunction}{\addplot[smooth, ultra thick, domain=\XMin:\XMax, red]  {exp(x)-2} node [left] {$y=e^x-2$}}%
\newcommand*{\AddPlotAsymptote}{\addplot[smooth, thin,        domain=\XMin:\XMax, blue] {-2} node [below left] {$y=-2$}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
    \AddPlotFunction;
    \AddPlotAsymptote;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Moving a tick mark on each axis but keeping the default tick marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210586/moving-a-tick-mark-on-each-axis-but-keeping-the-default-tick-marks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to supply the `fill` option to `extra y tick style={y tick label style={<options>}}`.

This is similar to how you need to supply it to `y tick label style`, not `y tick style` in case you're using "normal" ticks. Unfortunately, there's no `every y tick label style`, so you'll have to use `y tick label style` inside `extra y tick style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\XMin}{-2.2}%
\newcommand{\XMax}{1.5}%

\pgfplotsset{
    My Axis Style/.append style={
        width=7cm, height=8cm,
        xmin=\XMin, xmax=\XMax, ymin=-3.2, ymax=2.5,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        ytick={-1,1,2},
        extra y ticks={-2},
        extra y tick style={
            y tick label style={
                fill=white,
                draw=none,
                inner sep=0pt,
                outer sep=0.3333em
            }       
        },
    }
}

\newcommand*{\AddPlotFunction}{\addplot[smooth, ultra thick, domain=\XMin:\XMax, red]  {exp(x)-2} node [left] {$y=e^x-2$}}%
\newcommand*{\AddPlotAsymptote}{\addplot[smooth, thin,        domain=\XMin:\XMax, blue] {-2} node [below left] {$y=-2$}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
    \AddPlotFunction;
    \AddPlotAsymptote;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```