# Moving a tick mark on each axis but keeping the default tick marks

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to move one tick mark on the x-axis and one tick mark on the y-axis. The only tick mark, labeled `16,000/3\sqrt{3}`, should be moved to the right side of the y-axis, and the tick mark, labled `20/\sqrt{3}` should be moved above the x-axis.  There must be a specification similar to `yticklabel style={anchor=west},` to use.

Also, the graph writes over several tick marks. I thought that the specification `fill=white` would prevent this from happening.  I remember that there is a command to print the axes over the graph.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-25,xmax=25,
    domain=-25:25,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3100,ymax=3100,
    restrict y to domain=-3100:3100,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={11.547},
    extra x tick labels={$\frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}$},
    extra y ticks={3079.2},
    extra y tick labels={$\frac{16,000}{3\sqrt{3}}$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:20,blue] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=20:25,blue] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=-25:0,blue] {400*x - x^3} node[right,pos=0.25,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 400x - x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set control the placement of the `extra x/y ticks label`s via the `extra x/y tick style`:

```
extra x tick style={x tick label style={above, yshift=0.6ex}},
extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=0.3em}},
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can place the labels via a `\node` using the `axis cs` coordinate system:

```
\node [above] at (axis cs: 11.547,0) {\tiny$\frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}$};
\node [right] at (axis cs: 0,3079.2) {\tiny$\frac{16,000}{3\sqrt{3}}$};
```

### Notes:

- As far as your question regarding overwriting the nodes, that is what `fill=white` is doing. You can see the size of the nodes if you add `draw=red`. i.e., `ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white, draw=red}`. This additional padding is controlled via `inner sep`, so setting this to zero via `ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white, draw=red, inner sep=0}` you will see that the nodes are now only the size of the text and the overlapps is reduced (except of course when the actual text overlap other text).

### References:

- [Style to make axis tick label opaque using "extra y tick" feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51862/style-to-make-axis-tick-label-opaque-using-extra-y-tick-feature)
- [Style to make axis tick label opaque](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/style-to-make-axis-tick-label-opaque)

---

### Code: `extra x/y tick style`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-25,xmax=25,
    domain=-25:25,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3100,ymax=3100,
    restrict y to domain=-3100:3100,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    extra x tick style={x tick label style={above, yshift=0.6ex}},
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={right, xshift=0.3em}},
    xtick={},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={11.547},
    extra x tick labels={$\frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}$},
    extra y ticks={3079.2},
    extra y tick labels={$\frac{16,000}{3\sqrt{3}}$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:20,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=20:25,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=-25:0,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3} node[right,pos=0.25,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 400x - x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

### Code: `\node` placement

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-25,xmax=25,
    domain=-25:25,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3100,ymax=3100,
    restrict y to domain=-3100:3100,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={11.547},
    extra x tick labels={},% <-- placed via a \node
    extra y ticks={3079.2},
    extra y tick labels={},% <-- placed via a \node
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:20,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=20:25,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3};
\addplot[samples=501,dashed,domain=-25:0,blue, ultra thick] {400*x - x^3} node[right,pos=0.25,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 400x - x^{3}$};

\node [above] at (axis cs: 11.547,0) {\tiny$\frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}$};
\node [right] at (axis cs: 0,3079.2) {\tiny$\frac{16,000}{3\sqrt{3}}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```